# Replace XML node / string

Tags: c#

I have two serialized XML objects like:

```
<car id="1">
  <name>Renault</name>
  <type>
    <gear>Manual</gear>
    <petrol>Gas</petrol>
    <model>11</model>
  </type>
  <status>Available</status>
</car>
```

And another just being a tag:

```
<type>
 <gear>Automatic</gear>
</type>
```

I want to replace the type node from the first object with the node from the second object.

I tried:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"<type>(.*)</type>", replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But it doesn't give the desired output. Any suggestions?

Comment: **Don't use** regex to handle XML! Use the proper XML classes (`XmlDocument` etc. or Linq-to-XML with `XDocument`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this my `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml("<car id=\"1\"><name>Renault</name><type><gear>Manual</gear><petrol>Gas</petrol><model>11</model></type><status>Available</status></car>");

var typeNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::car[@id='1']/type");

if (typeNode != null) typeNode.InnerText = "<gear>Automatic</gear>";

string str = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use you own function with substring, like this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(NodeReplace(xml, "type",value));
    }

    public string NodeReplace(string xml, string nodeToFind, string newValue)
    {
        int start = xml.IndexOf("<" + nodeToFind);
        int end = xml.IndexOf("</" + nodeToFind + ">");

        string toreplace = xml.Substring(start, end + 3 + (nodeToFind.Length) - start);
        xml = xml.Replace(toreplace, newValue);
        return xml;
    }
```

but if you want a recomendation, i think is better serialize with a class and simple replace you node like a variable